# Unterschied zwischen „in Wirklichkeit“, „vielmehr“ und „eigentlich“

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice, adverb

> Sie kennen sich. Sie sind **in Wirklichkeit** gute Freunde.
>
> Sie kennen sich. Sie sind **vielmehr** gute Freunde.
>
> Sie kennen sich. Sie sind **eigentlich** gute Freunde.

Meine Fragen sind: Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den drei Adverbien und haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung im Zusammenhang?

Comment: Also "vielmehr" hebt sich deutlich von den beiden ab und die Frage sollte mit Hilfe eines jeden Wörterbuchs beantwortet werden können. "Eigentlich" hat tatsächlich die Definition "in Wahrheit" und ist somit synonym zu "in Wirklichkeit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Wirklichkeit** unterstellt für mich, ähnlich wie es Medi auch schon vorgeschlagen hat, dass es auch eine Unwirklichkeit gibt. Vielleicht spielen die beiden in einem Theaterstück Erzfeinde oder dergleichen. Der Ausdruck in diesem Zusammenhang wirkt auf mich etwas schief.

> Ja, im Stück können sie sich auf den Tod nicht ausstehen, aber in Wirklichkeit sind sie gute Freunde.

**Vielmehr** verstärkt, völlig ohne Ironie, das Gesagte. So, wie *gute Freunde sein* stärker ist, als sich bloß zu kennen, kann *vielmehr* auch anderswo eingesetzt werden, wo ein erster Eindruck zu kurz kommt (aber nicht unbedingt täuscht). Ohne den Kontext zu kennen, würde ich vermuten, dass man die beiden, von denen man nicht gewusst hat, dass sie einander kennen, bei einer alltäglichen Freundlichkeit oder Ähnlichem beobachtet hat, und daraus einen zu kurzen Schluss (»Ach, kennen sie sich?«) gezogen hat, den das Gegenüber mit besagtem Satz vervollständigt. Man könnte es ersetzen durch *sogar, außerdem, darüber hinaus* und Ähnliches.

> Du hast Recht. Sie kennen sich nicht nur, sie sind vielmehr gute Freunde.

Andererseits kann es auch verwendet werden, um das Gegenteil einer vorherigen Aussage zu verstärken.

> Sie hassen sich nicht. Sie sind vielmehr gute Freunde.

**Eigentlich** hat den Beiklang, dass man etwas wahrgenommen hat, das so gar nicht zu dem passt, was tatsächlich der Fall ist. Man hat also irgendeine Situation wahrgenommen, die einen das völlige Gegenteil erwarten lässt, wird dann aber belehrt, dass der Eindruck verkehrt war, und etwas anderes zutrifft.

> Naja, von dem Streit könnte man meinen, sie mögen sich nicht. Aber eigentlich sind sie gute Freunde.

Answer (score 1):

Also spontan würde ich sagen:

- *In Wirklichkeit*: Klingt für mich so, als würden die Gemeinten so tun, als wären sie keine Freunde.

  D. h.: *in Wirklichkeit* = *tatsächlich*, *in Wahrheit, *genau genommen*, *im wahren Leben* oder *in der [Realität](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wirklichkeit)* (z.B. bei Schauspielern)
- *Vielmehr*: Klingt für mich—in diesem Zusammenhang—etwas konstruiert, also etwas was weniger geläufig ist. Angenommen so ein Satz würde fallen, würde ich *vielmehr* so verstehen, dass man auf den ersten Eindruck denken würde, sie verstehen sich nicht oder sind (eher) keine Freunde. D. h. eine vorangegangene Aussage wird richtig gestellt oder korrigiert (siehe auch [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vielmehr)).

  Aber *vielmehr* hat die Bedeutung *eigentlich*, *jedoch*, *genau genommen*.
- *Eigentlich*: Tendenziell würde ich sagen, dies ist ähnlich wie *vielmehr*, aber hier muss der erste Eindruck noch deutlich unklarer gewesen sein, so dass auch der Zusammenhang zwischen Wirklichkeit und dem Schein (erster Eindruck) größer ist.

  Also ich würde sagen, *eigentlich* ist eine leichte Abstufung von *in Wirklichkeit* und eine starke "Aufstockung" von *vielmehr* (siehe auch [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eigentlich)).

  D. h.: *eigentlich* = *im Prinzip*, *in Wahrheit*, *im engeren Sinne*, *genau genommen*.